# ¿Cómo acceder a los datos del Web Service del DANE (SIPSA) desde R?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, xml, webservice, xml-schema

He estado intentando obtener los datos que provee el DANE (Colombia) a través de su Web Service: http://appweb.dane.gov.co:9001/sipsaWS/SrvSipsaUpraBeanService?WSDL

En el siguiente enlace se encuentra un instructivo con la información que provee este Web Service: https://www.dane.gov.co/index.php/estadisticas-por-tema/agropecuario/sistema-de-informacion-de-precios-sipsa/servicio-web-para-consulta-de-la-base-de-datos-de-sipsa

Hasta el momento lo que he conseguido es acceder a la url, ingresar a su "raíz", que es donde en teoría se encuentran las tablas con los datos:

```
url <- GET("http://appweb.dane.gov.co:9001/sipsaWS/SrvSipsaUpraBeanService?WSDL")

url1 <- xmlTreeParse(url)

raiz <-xmlRoot(url1)
```

```
raiz

<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://servicios.sipsa.co.gov.dane/" xmlns:tns="http://servicios.sipsa.co.gov.dane/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr" type="tns:consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr"/>
 <xs:element name="consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadrResponse" type="tns:consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadrResponse"/>
 <xs:element name="promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr" type="tns:promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr"/>
 <xs:element name="promedioAbasSipsaMesMadrResponse" type="tns:promedioAbasSipsaMesMadrResponse"/>
 <xs:element name="promediosSipsaCiudad" type="tns:promediosSipsaCiudad"/>
 <xs:element name="promediosSipsaCiudadResponse" type="tns:promediosSipsaCiudadResponse"/>
 <xs:element name="promediosSipsaMesMadr" type="tns:promediosSipsaMesMadr"/>
 <xs:element name="promediosSipsaMesMadrResponse" type="tns:promediosSipsaMesMadrResponse"/>
 <xs:element name="promediosSipsaParcial" type="tns:promediosSipsaParcial"/>
 <xs:element name="promediosSipsaParcialResponse" type="tns:promediosSipsaParcialResponse"/>
 <xs:element name="promediosSipsaSemanaMadr" type="tns:promediosSipsaSemanaMadr"/>
 <xs:element name="promediosSipsaSemanaMadrResponse" type="tns:promediosSipsaSemanaMadrResponse"/>
 <xs:complexType name="promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr">
  <xs:sequence/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="promedioAbasSipsaMesMadrResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="return" type="tns:sipsaAbastecimientosMesMadr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="sipsaAbastecimientosMesMadr">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="artiId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="artiNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="cantidadTon" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="enviado" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fechaCreacion" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fechaMesIni" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fuenId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fuenNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="futiId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="tmpAbasMesId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="promediosSipsaSemanaMadr">
  <xs:sequence/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="promediosSipsaSemanaMadrResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="return" type="tns:sipsaMayoristasSemanaMadr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="sipsaMayoristasSemanaMadr">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="artiId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="artiNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="enviado" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fechaCreacion" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fechaIni" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fuenId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fuenNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="futiId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="maximoKg" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="minimoKg" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="promedioKg" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="tmpMayoSemId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="promediosSipsaCiudad">
  <xs:sequence/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="promediosSipsaCiudadResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="return" type="tns:sipsaPromMayoristasCiudad" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="sipsaPromMayoristasCiudad">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="ciudad" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="codProducto" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="enviado" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fechaCaptura" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fechaCreacion" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="precioPromedio" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="producto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="regId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="promediosSipsaParcial">
  <xs:sequence/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="promediosSipsaParcialResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="return" type="tns:sipsaPromediosMayoristasParcial" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="sipsaPromediosMayoristasParcial">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="artiNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="deptNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="enmaFecha" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fuenId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fuenNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="futiId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="grupNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="idArtiSemana" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="maximoKg" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="minimoKg" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="muniId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="muniNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="promedioKg" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadrResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="return" type="tns:sipsaInsumosMesMadr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="sipsaInsumosMesMadr">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="deptNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="enviado" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fechaCreacion" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fechaMesIni" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="insumoNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="muniId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="muniNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="promedio" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="tireId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="tireNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="tmpInsMesId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="promediosSipsaMesMadr">
  <xs:sequence/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="promediosSipsaMesMadrResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="return" type="tns:sipsaMayoristasMesMadr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="sipsaMayoristasMesMadr">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="artiId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="artiNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="enviado" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fechaCreacion" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fechaMesIni" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fuenId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="fuenNombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="futiId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="maximoKg" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="minimoKg" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="promedioKg" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="tmpMayoMesId" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Sin embargo, no entiendo de qué forma puedo acceder a las tablas con los datos. Los ejemplos que he encontrado asumen que los datos aparecen dentro de la estructura XML, sin embargo acá no aparecen por ninguna parte.

Una de las tablas a las cuales podría acceder es esta:

[image: Ejemplo de tabla de datos SIPSA DANE]

Agradecería si alguien con experiencia en obtener datos desde este tipo de objetos me puede brindar consejos sobre cómo proceder.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes que usar las operaciones descritas. Prueba con un cliente como SOAPui y trata de consumir una a una las operaciones. Este cliente va a crear mensajes de prueba para cada operación y podrás ver de qué va consumir el web service. Lo que llamas tablas son realmente los tipos de mensaje que se usan de entrada y salida descritos en el WSDL, pero con hacer GET del WSDL no estás consumiendo el web service, sólo estás leyendo el contrato WSDL

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, muchas gracias por la observación. Si, tenías toda la razón, me faltaba ese paso intermedio para poder acceder realmente a los datos. Muchas gracias.